# Advantage of using ast to modify the source of a function

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I was reading a code recipe that used a decorator to add code to a function's body using the `ast` module. Specifically, the code added lowers some global variables to the local scope. The ast object is then compiled to a create a code object which is attached to the function's `__code__` attribute. The decorator code goes like this:

```
def lower_names(*namelist):
    def lower(func):
        srclines = inspect.getsource(func).splitlines()
        for n, line in enumerate(srclines):
            if '@lower_names' in line:
                break
        src = '\n'.join(srclines[n+1:])
        top = ast.parse(src, mode='exec')

        c1 = NameLower(namelist) # an ast.NodeVisitor subclass that has a
                                 # method to transform the ast node
        c1.visit(top)
        temp = {}
        exec(compile(top, '', 'exec'), temp, temp)
        func.__code__ = temp[func.__name__].__code__
        return func
    return lower
```

My question is why is ast being used at all? Why not simply modify the function source with the code to lower the globals and compile this directly (instead of creating an ast object), and attach the code object to the function? Is there any advantage (like speed) to using ast?

Comment: If you wanted to do this via direct manipulation of the source code, how would you tell that a given portion of the source actually *is* a global variable, and not just random text in the middle of a string literal or a comment?  Doing this right would be considerably more complicated than just using the existing tools for the job.

Comment: The code to lower globals is simple. It just uses the `globals()` builtin to create the local variables for the names passed in.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for using ast could be the effort needed to modify the function directly. The right number of spaces or tabs would need to be inserted before the added code to match the indentation level of the function body. So it is better to create and modify the ast instead.